# NodeJS is swallowing my exception thrown from a callback

Tags: node.js

Assume the following code:

```
myModule.doStuff(options, function(err, results) {
    if (err) console.log('e', err);
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(results);
});
```

The offending code is:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    try {
        throw new Error('test error');
        resolve('success');
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log('r', ex);
        reject(ex);
    }
});
```

And then farther up the chain:

```
self.adapter
    .collect(self.options)
    .then(function(data) {
        self.callback(null, data);
        if (self.runnable) {
            setTimeout(self.collect.bind(self), 2000);
        }
    }, function(error) {
        self.callback(error);
    });
```

The 'e [error info here]' statement prints, but the throw statement is apparently ignored. The app happily continues doing whatever else it was instructed to do and does not crash as expected. Why?

Comment: Well is this your module, and have you set an event handler for 'uncaughtException'?

Comment: Nope. Internally, the module uses the promise library. It has a try/catch surrounding the offending code and calls reject(e) inside the catch statement. I can verify that this code is executing properly because the console.log statement directly above the throw statement prints the expected error. Only the throw statement is being ignored here.

Comment: To add, the intermediate code that handles the reject from the promise then in turn executes the callback function with the error as the first parameter.

Comment: Unless it provides some error handling mechanism that I'm not aware of, that library is quite terrible IMO, the promise used internally is swallowing up your exception.

Comment: Can you name your functions in that example code in a way that can be followed? Is that `offending code` in a function? When is `myModule.doStuff`called in your error example "further up the chain"? Provide a little more context and we'll sort it out.

Comment: I'll see if I can put together a demo to repro the issue when I have a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never found the answer with the specific library I was using, but after switching to the Q library, it exposed a crucial step that I may have been missing before also. If there is no reject handler at the top level of the promise chain, the exception may be swallowed. According to the Q documentation, the way around this is to always call `.done()` at the top of the chain which flushes any pending exceptions back to the caller.